# Random process Mean function and Correlation function

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, correlation, means, random-functions

Suppose $Z(t)=Σ_{k=1}^{n}Xe^{j(_0t+_k)}$, $t∈R$ where $_0$ is a constant, $n$ is a fixed positive integer, $X_1,...,X_n,　_1,...,_n$ are mutually independent random variables, and $EX_k=0, DX_k=σ_{k}^{2}, $~$U[0,2π], k=1,2,...,n$.
Find the mean function and correlation function of {Z(t), t ∈ R}.

I have tried to solve it.

For mean function,

$m_Z(s)=E\{Z_s\}=E\{X_s\}+iE\{Y_t\}$
$=E\{Σ_{k=1}^{s}Xe^{j(_0t+_k)}\}$

For correlation function,

$R_Z(s,u)=E\{Z_s,Z_u\}$
$=E\{Y(s)Y(u)\}$
$=E\{Σ_{k=1}^{s}Xe^{j(_0t+_k)}Σ_{k=1}^{u}Xe^{j(_0t+_k)}\}$
$=E\{Σ_{k=1}^{s}Σ_{k=1}^{u} Xe^{j(_0t+_k)}Xe^{j(_0t+_k)}\}$

I am stuck here. How to move from here ahead?

Comment: Confusing mishmash of notation. Is $i=j=\sqrt{-1}$? Does $Z_{t}$ mean the same as $Z(t)$? Where does $Y_{t}$ come from? What does $DX_{k}$ indicate? What are we supposed to make of $\sum_{k=1}^{s}\sum_{k=1}^{u}\cdots$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before finding the mean and variance function, one has to fix the notation of $Z(t)$, which should be
$$
Z(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_ke^{j(_0t+\Phi_k)}.
$$
In  order to compute the mean of $Z(t)$, it suffices to compute the expectation of $X_ke^{j(_0t+\Phi_k)}$. To do so, use the independence between $X_k$ and $\Phi_k$ and the fact that $X_k$ is centered.

For the correlation function, the most technical part is to compute $\operatorname{Cov}\left(Z(s),Z(t)\right)$ which actually reduces to compute
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{\ell=1}^n\mathbb E\left[X_kX_\ell e^{j(\omega_0s+\Phi_k)}e^{j(\omega_0t+\Phi_\ell)}\right]
$$
(when you have to sums, it is always preferable to sum over different indices).
If $k\neq\ell$, the corresponding term vanishes.